# Autotools (AX_PYTHON_DEVEL and AM_PATH_PYTHON)

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I want to find python above 3.4 which has python-devel.
I came up with this piece of code in configure.ac:

```
AM_PATH_PYTHON([3.4],
          [AX_PYTHON_DEVEL([>= '3.4'])],
          [AC_MSG_FAILURE([Cannot find python.])]
         )]
```

But this doesn't catch this bad scenario:
Machine has python3.4, python3.6 and python3.6-devel

In this case, AM_PATH_PYTHON will find python 3.4 and AX_PYTHON_DEVEL will fail.

So, my question is: what is the best way to fill such requirement?

In pseudo-code, the logic should be something like this:

```
for ver in python_version_list; do
   AM_PATH_PYTHON($ver, AX_PYTHON_DEVEL($ver), [:]
   if "x$pythonexists" != "x:"
      break
done
AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_PYTHON], [test "x$pythonexists" = "xyes"])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that `AX_PYTHON_DEVEL` does not provide for searching multiple Python installations for development components -- neither internally nor externally.  It chooses one Python interpreter (which choice you can influence in various ways) and then expects to be able to identify and report back the development components associated with that interpreter.  If it cannot do so then it aborts configuration.

But I think you may have framed the problem unhelpfully.  The question ought not to be for which Python there exist development components, but rather for which Python the user wants your module / package installed.  It is reasonable to suppose that they want it for the system's default Python, if any, or certainly for a user-specified Python.  But in the face of multiple installed Pythons, it is not really reasonable to suppose that they want it for whatever random, new enough Python happens to have development components available.

Thus, I would simply do this:

```
# By default, aborts if no suitable Python is found:
AM_PATH_PYTHON([3.4])

# Will assume the Python interpreter previously identified by AM_PATH_PYTHON:
AX_PYTHON_DEVEL
```

Someone building your package in an environment where they have to contend with multiple Pythons will need to be savvy enough to deal with that situation no matter what, and in this case that would mean using the `PYTHON` environment variable to specify which Python to use (as `configure --help` will hint) if that turns out to be needed.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use these scripts\APIs with "for", and it just doesn't work :(
Possible directions are 1) to build with concrete python version or 2) to do new AX_PYTHON_DEVEL to what I need.

Comment: Virtually every use of Python uses at least one common Python package too.  So even if `AX_PYTHON_DEVEL` searched through multiple versions for one that had development components installed, one would be right back at the same problem if that version doesn't have e.g. Numpy installed and another version does.